# Visio resize of subfigures

Tags: visio

[Follow this link for Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMvPq.jpg)
Hello World,

I need some help with Visio. I am working on two rectangles (R1 and R2) [like the one shown here 'Figure 1'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMvPq.jpg).

The catch is I want smaller rectangle (R2) to NOT change its size and position relative to rectangle 1 (R1) when I resize the gouping of R1 and R2. In developer mode, I tried protecting the height and width of R2 (steps: In developer tab -> Protection -> width, height ), it does put a lock on resizing R2.

However when I group R1 and R2 and resize R1, the grouping makes even R2 change its size like the one shown in Figure 2 but I want something like Figure 3 where I should be able to resize the grouping of R1 and R2 but keep R2 unchanged in its size and position relative to R1 (sorry for the repeatation).

I achieved in locking the size of R2 and resizing the grouping of R1 and R2 (steps: In developer tab -> Behaviour -> reposition only ), however, R2 now keeps on changing its position as shown in Figure 4. I am using Visio 2016 Professional.

Any help would greately be appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: Please note this question is offtopic on stackoverflow - it is not a programming question. You may be of better luck trying another stack exchange site (SuperUser), or Visio-specific forum (such as VisGuy forum)

Comment: As Nikolay said, wrong place to post, but take a look your Shape after you've grouped them. After grouping the two shapes are subshapes of a third (now top-level) shape. You can still edit the group by right clicking the shape and use Group-->Edit. Then I advise you to learn to manipulate the ShapeSheet, there you can change just about every aspect of the shape. An alternate solution would be to make one Shape with a second geometry, which than has fixed coordinates in relation to the shape size/position.